# Why erasing element from map while looping it is not causing crash everytime it happens?

Tags: c++, clang, c++20, c++98

So, here is my function

```
void Timers::RemoveTimer(DWORD id)
{
    auto it = m_mapTimers.begin();
    for ( ; it != m_mapTimers.end(); ++it) {
        if (it->first.second == id) {
            m_mapTimers.erase(it);
        }
    }
}
```

And it clearly should not remove element this way, but what is interesting to me, is why the crash is not constant? Program can call this function few thousand times untill it goes down.

Also, kind of side question, why there was no crashes on c++98? I get them after porting to c++20, without any change to class.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase : **References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other references and iterators are not affected.** If your program has undefined behavior (as you don't follows the invalidation rules by using `it` after deleting the corresponding map element), then hard to explain behavior is possible. A checked debug version can help find such mistake. But in C++, you are mostly responsible for reading, understanding and following the documentation. Generally, it is pointless to try to explain **undefined behavior**

Comment: @Phil1970 I know i shouldnt put too much time into undefined behavior, but its really baffling to me.

So i did some testing and it turns out that it will only crash when there is just one element to erase, at least now i know why its not constant. Now my only question is, why it wasnt crashing on c++98 when i was using boost?

Comment: @Alkyone if you want to figure that out, you'll need to learn more about what causes a crash and what doesn't.  (typically a crash is caused either by the processor trying to dereference a virtual-memory address that is not mapped to any valid page, or by some bit of library code noticing that a precondition hasn't been met and triggering an assertion failure; it could be either of those in this case).  In particular, bad memory usage (e.g. use-after-free) doesn't *necessarily* cause a crash, e.g. if the memory location read/written happens to map to a valid/accessible physical page.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Well, last call before crash goes to `__tree_is_left_child`, which is called from `__tree_iterator& operator++()` and `__tree_next_iter`, so my guess is that when last element from map is removed, it tries to acces next one but there is none?

Comment: @Alkyone seems plausible; running the buggy program under valgrind (or similar) might yield some clues.

Comment: Another thing to remember is that recent compilers optimize more agressively the code assuming that your code **is free from undefined behavior**.  When it happen, it is very hard to reason about it. Given that the branch is you loop has undefined behavior, the compiler might assume that the condition is always false and thus that the loop is useless. In a case like yours, a more plausible explanation would be that the old compiler leave the removed node intact while the new one modify it immediatly.

Answer (score 2):

To safely remove elements from a container you should write it like this:

```
void Timers::RemoveTimer(DWORD id)
{
    auto it = m_mapTimers.begin();
    for ( ; it != m_mapTimers.end(); ) {
        if (it->first.second == id) {
            it = m_mapTimers.erase(it);
            continue;
        }
        it++;
    }
}
```

As for your question, this code may crash if it violates a memory segment that does not belong to it by trying to access it.
It depends where the memory you are accessing is located in the address space, which is different every time the program runs.